# Passing mysql_insert_id from PHP to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

AJAX:

```
function saveUserData(userData){
    $.post('submithuman.php', {firstname: document.getElementById('firstname').value,
    userData: JSON.stringify(userData)},
    function(data){ alert(data)});
```

PHP:

```
  $id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $id;
```

How do I pass this correctly?

Comment: no need to encode if need return only id.

Comment: How do I pass it back into AJAX though? Are you sure I don't need to encode?

Comment: just echo id from php and your ajax success data will give you that id.

Comment: yeah, I don't know how to correctly pass it thought Ajax with success data, I am pretty new to Ajax

Comment: The data attribute you get in the callback function should be the output of your PHP code. So instead of `return true;` try `return data;`

Comment: Still not having any luck...

Comment: Please go read [ask], and learn how to _properly_ describe problems - “not working” isn’t it, and neither is “still not having any luck”. What happens, instead of what you expect to happen? Should it be just “nothing”, then have you at least checked the browser console for errors, and also checked what the request was actually answered with in the network panel?

Comment: Super embarrassing, that part of the code was working - there was a server error. Super sorry, code below is working.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way to return data corresponding to ajax is in JSON Object form. So you should return it as:

```
json_encode(["id" => $id]);
```

And it will be shown as:

```
{"id": "id value"}
```

**Reason:** Data in JSON Object form can be verified easily. `id` key easily can be checked by using `hasOwnProperty` function in JS. But in case of only string rather than json data, any error could be easily treated as desired output which might confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

See my sample code. You can get idea from it.

**AJAX code**

```
$.post( "submithuman.php", function( id ) {
    alert(id)
});
```

PHP code

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
 echo $id ;
```